# Javascript give undefined error

Tags: javascript

`undefined`

HTML Code

```
<a id="int" onclick="level('int')" value="4">L1</a>
```

javascript Code:

```
function level(str) {
    var lev=document.getElementById(str).value;
    document.write(lev); // enter code here
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Try `getAttribute('value')` instead of `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only form control elements have a `value` attribute and property. You can use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead:

```
<a id="int" onclick="level('int')" data-value="4">L1</a>

function level(str) {
    var lev=document.getElementById(str).getAttribute('data-value');
    document.write(lev);
}
```

A slightly better version of your code:

```
<a id="int" onclick="level(this)" data-value="4">L1</a>

function level(element) {
    var lev = element.getAttribute('data-value');
    console.log(lev);
}
```

[Learn more about event handling.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Comment: Then you have a problem somewhere else in your code, or you didn't follow my suggestions properly, because it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dbaH8/.